# How to travel a list n by n elements

Tags: list, prolog

So I wasn't expecting to post that much more today, but I'm dumbfounded not being able to do this task. I have working code for traveling an input list 3 by 3 elements. But I just realized it only works for lists of 3 elements, when I input 4 it fails. Makes sense. So I'm trying to make a rule that takes each element one by one, travelling both lists in this way, and since both lists are equally long, they should stop at the same time, and my output list should formed same as before!

But not a chance, it straight up fails. I think I'm looking at this problem the wrong way because it's not a so difficult task.

original, working idea for 3 elements:

```
crearEnum(_, [], []).
crearEnum([Ha,Hb,Hc], [[H1,H2,H3]| PermNodes], [[enum(H1,Ha), enum(H2,Hb), enum(H3,Hc)] |SalidaCreacionEnum]):-
    crearEnum([Ha,Hb,Hc], PermNodes, SalidaCreacionEnum).
```

What I got so far:

I call it with this (it's part of a bigger rule):

```
crearEnum(NodeListUnique, IDsPermuted, [], SalidaCreacionEnum),


crearEnum(_, [], L, L).
crearEnum(NodeListUnique, [CabezaPermNodes| PermNodes], [EnumsFormados |EntradaCreacionEnum], SalidaCreacionEnum):-
    formaEnums(NodeListUnique, CabezaPermNodes, EnumsFormados),
    crearEnum(NodeListUnique, PermNodes, EntradaCreacionEnum, SalidaCreacionEnum).

formaEnums([],[],_).
formaEnums([Ha|NodeListUnique], [H1|CabezaPermNodes], [enum(H1,Ha)|EnumsFormados]):-
    formaEnums(NodeListUnique, CabezaPermNodes, EnumsFormados).
```

And a trace that is the reason I'm dumbfounded as to me failing this hard:

```
Call:crearEnum([c, b, a], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]], [], _G5349)
 Fail:crearEnum([c, b, a], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]], [], _G5349)
```

Basically because I've been doing similar operations but this one straight up fails. I guess it's because unifying or the base case?? But I don't see much diference with other lists I do see how are being travelled and they work so don't really know what is so wrong about this.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamendal issue in this case is that `[First|Rest]`  means something different than you think it does. It means a list whose first **element** is `First`. It does *not* mean "a list that begins with the elements *contained* in `First`". So, if `First` is itself a *list*, then `[First|Rest]` is a list whose first *element* is a list.

The issue manifests itself in particular in `[EnumsFormados|EntradaCreacionEnum]`, where `EnumsFormados` is *itself* a list.

Reasonsing about lists that are described throughout multiple predicates can be  quite error-prone and cumbersome, and for this reason, we have **DCG notation** ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) in Prolog: It makes describing lists much easier, in particular if the description of a single list spans multiple rules.

I give you one example that is loosely related to your use case. With small modifications, you may be able to use this DCG to describe lists that matter to you. I shall describe a list of terms of the form `enum(Unique,Node)`.

```
enums([], _) --> [].
enums([U|Us], Nodes) -->
    enums_(Nodes, U),
    enums(Us, Nodes).

enums_([], _) --> [].
enums_([N|Nodes], U) -->
    [enum(U,N)],
    enums_(Nodes, U).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- phrase(enums([a,b], [x,y,z]), Ls).
Ls = [enum(a, x), enum(a, y), enum(a, z), enum(b, x), enum(b, y), enum(b, z)].
```

Note that the arguments *need not* have the same length! Note also that the definition spans multiple clauses, yet it is very easy to describe the list's elements. The DCG syntax **`[Terminal]`** is used to state that a specific Prolog term `Terminal` occurs at that position in the described list.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found it. I was trying to separate head and tail of an empty list, so answer is, it fails, can't be done.

So it should be like this:

```
crearEnum(NodeListUnique, [CabezaPermNodes| PermNodes], [EntradaCreacionEnum], SalidaCreacionEnum):-
```

if it's going to be called with an empty list. That took WAY longer than it should.

Comment: I somehow doubt that this is the right solution. It would be better to eiither use [tag:dcg] to describe a list, or successively instantiate a given list further. The latter means that you will likely have a goal like `Ls = [First|Rest]` somewhere, or a pattern like `[First|Rest]` in the *head* of the clause.

Comment: Could I see some example already done of successively instantiating a given list further? I feel like that would make my code much more easy to not only read but also it's performance, but as of right now I'm stuck with this solution (like, I now think that is the way to solve this kind of problems, and don't really see another). As for dcg, I might try it later but I'm not sure I'm going to master it in the time I have :(